# Is there any options for always passing pipeline even though cypress tests fails on Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
"instance1": "CYPRESS_API_URL='http://localhost:1234/' cy2 run --record --parallel --config video=false -e TAGS='not @cleanup and @focus' --key sofy-automation --ci-build-id `date +%F+%H+%M`",
"cleanup-instance": "CYPRESS_API_URL='http://localhost:1234/' cy2 run --record --parallel --config video=false -e TAGS='@cleanup' --key sofy-automation --ci-build-id `date +%F+%H+%M`",
"parallel": "npm-run-all --sequential delete:reports --parallel --continue-on-error instance1 instance1 instance1 --sequential cleanup-instance --sequential combine:reports"
```

Above are my cypress test script running on vsts Microsoft azure pipeline.
Whenever any test case gets failed , it fails entire pipeline also.
I have configured through Yaml file.

```
- task: Yarn@2
  displayName: 'run parallel'
  inputs:
  ProjectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  Arguments: 'parallel'
  workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  verbose: 'true'
```

Is there any way to pass build pipeline always true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [continueOnError property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#task) to make the pipeline continue, even if this task has failures:

```
- task: Yarn@2
  displayName: 'run parallel'
  inputs:
    ProjectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Arguments: 'parallel'
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    verbose: 'true'
  continueOnError: true
```